# How to pass a function and a value to the onchange HTML-attribute?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a project and I would like to know how to pass a function and a value within the `onchange` attribute.

For example I have the function `updateField()` and the value `$str`.

How to pass the function and value "onchange"?

```
<?php       
    $str = "refrescarPruebas(this.form)";   
    $rs =   consultaAplicacion();   
    echo '<div class="campo">'
        . '<select name="aplicacion" onchange="'.$str.'" class="normal_text">'
        . '<option value = "">Elija tipo de mensaje..</option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))  
        echo'<optionvalue="'.$row["id"],'">'.$row["id"].''.$row['descripcion'].'</option>';
    echo  '</select>'
    . '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax mistake.you need to give the space between option and their value.

```
<?php       
    $str = "refrescarPruebas(this.form)";   
    $rs =   consultaAplicacion();   
    echo '<div class="campo">'
        . '<select name="aplicacion" onchange="'.$str.'" class="normal_text">'
        . '<option value = "">Elija tipo de mensaje..</option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))  
        echo'<option value="'.$row["id"],'">'.$row["id"].''.$row['descripcion'].'</option>';
    echo  '</select>'
    . '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, updateField () is a separate function, and $ str is a separate value.
I do not understand the onChange () assignment you made.

Comment: $str you have assigned refrescarPruebas function which should be in javascript.And where you want to use updateField ?

Comment: you trying to call two function?

Comment: UpdateField () is a totally independent function, the idea is to pass the $str value and a function that does something else.

Comment: That means you want to pass `refrescarPruebas` function value to `updateField` function.Am i right?

Comment: No, in onChange, I want to pass the value $ srt Y dateField ()
For example onchange = "'updateField (),. $ Str.'"
So I do not know if you can do this

Comment: you can call any no of function with separation of `;`.Try this one  `onchange="'updateField();$str.'"`